# Storing data fast in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have this program that is currently graphing data received from the serial port at speeds of up to 48Kb/s. I also need it to store all this data as a file, so that it can be read both by the program and from the user afterwards, all of this affecting the performance of the program as little as possible.

I have been doing some research and one pretty good option would be to save it in a XML file. However, I am not sure if this will be fast enough to keep up with this amount of data, if the chosen format will affect this process or if it will be suitable for a such a large file.

Any comments regarding this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: So try it and find out.  If it's fast enough, then you're all set, if it's not, see how it performs and compare it to how it *needs* to perform, and now you have an actual problem that you can solve.

Comment: XML is a very bad option because you *can't* save individual records and have a well-formed file. What you describe sounds like an IoT project. A very common IoT format is "line delimited JSON" - storing a separate JSON record in each line. It's not exactly valid JSON but most IoT libraries recognize it

Comment: It will be dependent of what type of data you are storing. Is it structured(XML, SQL works great for that) or is it unstructured?

Comment: Writing speed should be fine.  The real question is how fast you need to read the data and if you are reading the data sequential or random.

Comment: @jdwen XML for IoT is awful. You need *all* the data before you can write a valid file. It's not used at all, unless it's for single records

Comment: @Pekuso how are you going to use that file? How are you going to process it? IoT libraries and cloud services work with AVRO, CSV, line-delimited JSON and other formats. You should pick a format that's easy to write *and* process.

Comment: Panagiotis : I do not agree that is is awful.  It is done all the time.

Comment: @jdweng not for IoT, which is the scenario described here. You can't write one record at a time, you need to write an entire document. The OP would have to save one file per record, or batch enough records before writing a single document. With any of the single-line formats used for IoT though, you can just append lines as they arrive

Comment: You can write one record at a time using XmlWriter().  Often Xml Log files have non-conventional xml where there is an array at root level which you can write using a SreamWriter() one record at a time.  I prefer xml over Jason where xml is easier to read by humans.

Comment: @jdwen humans would disagree. Just because you can store XML *snippets* instead of well-formed documents doesn't mean this common or used. Preferences or not, XML isn't used in IoT. The very fact that almost half of the content is useless (the closing tags), makes the format harder to read for humans *and* wastes space and bandwidth

Comment: @Pekuso if you don't want to use heavy database such as MSSQL or MySql you can always try SQLite as the datastore. It is flexible, fun and a very fine footprint. But you will have the flexibility of a database (not full fledged) and it would be better than an XML file.